# siunitx - bold decimal separator

Tags: siunitx

In this mwe, the first décimal separator is not bold, how to fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    unit-mode = text,
    locale=FR,
    detect-all,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}},
    text-micro=\ensuremath{\othermu},
    math-micro=\othermu,
}

\begin{document}

$\num[math-rm=\mathbf]{.1}$ \textbf{0,1} \textbf{\SI{.1}{\km}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following MWE demonstrates that `\mathbf` itself does also not yield a bold comma. You could alternatively use `\bm` from the eponymous package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}

\sisetup{
    unit-mode = text,
    locale=FR,
    detect-all,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}},
    text-micro=\ensuremath{\othermu},
    math-micro=\othermu,
}

\begin{document}
$\num[math-rm=\mathbf, mode=math]{.1}$ \textbf{0,1} \textbf{\SI{.1}{\km}}

$\mathbf{,},$

$\num[math-rm=\bm]{.1}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And for `SI`, `$\SI[math-rm=\bm,unit-math-rm=\mathbf,
 number-unit-product={\mbox{\bfseries\,}}]{.1}{\km}$`

Answer (score 2):

In math period and command are setup in a way that they don't react to mathbf. You could change this (be aware that this changes spacing and so font used by the chars. Depending on your real font setup it can have side effects):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    unit-mode = text,
    locale=FR,
    detect-all,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}},
    text-micro=\ensuremath{\othermu},
    math-micro=\othermu,
}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"2E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"2C}
\begin{document}

$1.234\quad 1,234\quad  \mathbf{1.234\quad 1,234} \quad\num[math-rm=\mathbf]{.1}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is to use a textfont: `\num[math-rm=\textbf]`.